# Improving Fastlane's runtime for Scan -> Gym -> Deploy

Tags: swift, travis-ci, fastlane

I've been trying to include [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/) in a CI environment where the following should happen:

- any commit to the `master` branch should trigger a test run and then a build into [Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).
- any commit to the `development` branch should trigger a test run and then a build into [Fabric Beta](https://fabric.io).
- any other commit or pull request should trigger a test run.

The lanes are working with all the code signing through `match`.

In order to avoid building twice I'm building through `Gym` and then `Scan` with `skip_build: true` and `clean: false`, as mentioned in [#3353](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3353).

Although this does seem to help with the build time, due to the amount of `cocoapods` dependencies, it goes over the 50 minute limit in [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/ivanbruel/SwipeIt/). (Feel free to check the build logs)

How can this be improved in terms of running time? (Aside from fixing the slow compiling Swift functions mentioned in [#3](https://github.com/ivanbruel/SwipeIt/issues/3))

For reference, here's my [Fastfile](https://github.com/ivanbruel/SwipeIt/blob/master/fastlane/Fastfile).

Comment: Can you use parallel builds? If so you could use matrix builds to have one for testing and the other for deploying.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can speed up your build phase is using ***prebuilt frameworks***. It's like importing `AVFoundation` or any other Apple toolkit on your project.

Try to identify which dependency is slowing the running time down and move it to a prebuilt framework.

[Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) is a nice tool that allows you to use prebuilt frameworks and manage dependencies as well. You can cache `Carthage` builds on your CI. Check out this great [blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/caching-carthage-con-circleci) on how you can achieve caching.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to re-use pre-built derived data for scan, gym and snapshot. Main reason for that is that those are builds for different architectures, with potentially different xcconfigs.